# knocking at very low rpm (borderline stalling)

Tags: engine, noise, sparkplugs

i have VW jetta 2.5 (manual) when i go uphill slowly in to second gear or in reverse, without throttle. due to very low engine speed (probably 150-350 rpm). i get weird knocking/pinging sound. is it detonation? could damage engine by this way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be letting your engine labor at such a low RPM.

Keep the revs above idle, probably > 1000 RPM.

If you need to drive that slowly, drop down a gear.

Yes, you could be causing damage to the pistons, conrods and crank bearings.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/21990/4152) and [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/9388/4152).